# Create another constructor with Dependecy Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

As i have this **child** class defined below.

```
    internal class ParserZillowForSale : Parser
    {
        public ParserZillowForSale(int threadsCount)
        : base(threadsCount) {}
    }
```

And have **base** class defined below.

```
public class Parser
{
   private readonly int _threadsCount;
   public Parser(int threadsCount = 10)
   {
      _threadsCount = threadsCount;
   }
}
```

Now as i'm trying to define **Dependency Injection** below.

```
    internal class ParserZillowForSale : Parser
    {
        private readonly List<ListingDetailsData> listings;
        private readonly ListingHeader _ListingHeader;
        public ParserZillowForSale(int threadsCount)
        : base(threadsCount) {}
        public ParserZillowForSale(List<ListingDetailsData> listingsD, ListingHeader _ListingHeaderD)
        {
            listings = listingsD;
            _ListingHeader = _ListingHeaderD;
        }
    }
```

As i try to call this **object**.

```
ParserZillowForSale ParserZillowForSale = new ParserZillowForSale(maxThreads)
```

It throws an exception and i want to call both with **DI and without**. Here is the error which i recieve in the **PostMan**.

> "Exception while executing function: ParserZilowForSale -> The type
> initializer for 'Parser.ParserZillowForSale' threw an exception. -> No
> valid combination of account information found.",
> "errorDetails": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception
> while executing function: ParserZilowForSale --->
> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for
> 'Parser.ParserZillowForSale' threw an exception. --->
> System.FormatException : No valid combination of account information
> found"

*As i don't want to pass multiple arguments on the **base keyword** so that's why i created another constructor.*

Comment: Hi Anushka, welcome to StackOverflow. Please prevent posting [exceptions of errors](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). Would you mind updating the question to instead include all the relevant exception details in textual format?

Comment: OK @Steven thank you i'll update it.

Comment: Also sorry if I sound too pedantic, but your question is not related to [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dependency-injection/info), because DI focuses on inserting services (classes with behavor) based on abstractions. If I'm not mistaken, what you are showing is basic object composition of (strongly coupled) data classes.

Comment: @Steven i require to call DI on another constructor even after i use first constructor with base keyword how can i achieve that any hint would be helpful.

Comment: Mhhh....It doesn't seem that error is related to the constructor unless you're hiding some code.

Comment: IMHO, your problem is not related to DI or construction at all. I guess there is some WebJob related code in the Parser constructor. I would start checking there.

Comment: @ilkerkaran if i remove the child class second constructor that has DI then it works.

Comment: @ilkerkaran i don't want to use like this way private List<ListingDetailsData> listings = new List<ListingDetailsData>(); and private ListingHeader _ListingHeader = new ListingHeader();

Comment: If you look at the exception, you can see that it is a type initialization exception. This means that there is some code that runs when the type (not the instance) is first used, and that fails. This code throws a FormatException. But since you didn't show that code, it's impossible to answer your question